# Trying to animate a property based on a custom control's event using xaml on WP7

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-phone-7

My XAML looks like this:

```
    <me:MyControl x:Name="Publisher">
        <me:MyControl.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="me:MyControl.MyEvent">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Publisher"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            To="1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger -->
        </me:MyControl.Triggers>
    </me:MyControl>
```

When this loads I get an exception saying

```
Attribute me:MyControl.MyEventvalue is out of range
```

I've tried

- me:MyControl.MyEvent
- MyControl.MyEvent
- MyEvent
- Publisher.MyEvent

What's the magic incantation to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've be looking at WPF examples, Silverlight doesn't directly support any trigger other than for the loaded event.

Consider using the `VisualStateManager` instead.  You then need to change the state via code on the event.